# Fixed "$\mathcal Set$" for continuous maps on compact spaces

Tags: general-topology, continuity, proof-writing, compactness

Let  $$f:X\rightarrow X$$  be  a  continuous  map  on  the  compact  metric  space  $X.$ Show  that  there  is  a  subset  $A\subset X$  such  that  $f(A)=A$.

Now  the  given  hint  is  that  to  consider $$A_1=f(A)\\and\ \ \ A_{n+1}=f(A_n)$$

Now  I  guess , the  case  would  be  the  sequence  $\{A_n\}$ is  decreasing satisfying $A_{n+1}\subset A_n$ $\forall n\in \mathbb N.$ Then  obviously  they  would  satisfy  ***F***inite **I**ntersection **P**roperty  and  *compactness*  would  assure  existence  of  a non-empty  intersection ,  say  $A$ . and  that  would  be  our  answer .  But  my  problem  is  that  I  cannot  show  that  $$A_{n+1}\subset A_n$$  holds .

Please  help  me  with  that .

Thanks.

Comment: Start with $A_1 = f(X)$. Then, since $A_1 \subseteq X$, $A_2 = f(A_1) \subseteq f(X) = A_1$, and you may continue inductively. Note that $A_i$ is compact for all $i$ by induction, since $X$ is compact and the continuous image of a compact set is compact. This means that $A_i$ is closed in $X$ for all $i$ as well, since compact subspaces of metric spaces (more generally, of Hausdorff spaces) are closed.

Comment: You can take $A = \emptyset$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A_1=f(X)$.| $A_2=f(A_1)$ .

Now $$f:X\rightarrow X$$  and  we  have $$A_1\subset X\\or,\ f(A_1)\subset f(X)=A_1\\i.e.\ A_2\subset A_1\\or,\ \ f(A_2)\subset f(A_1)\\i.e.A_3\subset A_2\\.\\.\\.\\.\\.\\so\ \ \ \ on.$$

Assume  that  this  holds  upto the  integer $n$. i.e.  $A_n\subset A_{n+1}.$

Then we see  $$f(A_n)\subset f(A_{n+1}\\i.e. A_{n+1}\subset A_{n+2}$$
And  our  result  is  proved  for  all  $n\in \mathbb N$.

Now  this  decreasing  sequence  and  each  is  compact  being  continuous  image  of  compact  spaces. And  since  for  any  $"n"$ ,  the  set  $A_n$  is  non-empty  we  have  that  $\{A_n\}_n$  satisfies  ***F***inite **I**ntersection **P**roperty . Now  compact  means  closed  in  the  metric  space. In a  compact  metric  space  *Every family  of  closed  sets  satisfying  **F.I.P.**  has a  non-empty  intersection.* So  $$\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\neq \Phi$$. Let $$\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n = A$$

Now $$f(\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n)=f(A)\\ \\or,\ \ \cap_{n=1}^{\infty}f(A_n)=f(A)\\ \\or,\ \ \cap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n=f(A)$$
So $$f(A)=A.$$

Proved.